# How to take multiple images links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request, python-requests, urllib

```
def get_links(statu, data, n_img, url, agent):
    if statu==0:
        print("The website doesn't response. Please try again later",end=" ")
    else:
        img_links=[]
        r=requests.get(url,headers=agent).text
        soup=BeautifulSoup(r,"lxml")
        results=soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"view"})
        results=soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"view"})
        results=soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"interaction-view"})
        results=soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"photo-list-photo-interaction"})
        # results=soup.find_all("a",attrs={"class":"overlay"},limit=n_img)
        print(results)
        for result in results:
            link=result.get("href")
            img_links.append(link)
        return img_links
```

In order to download multiple image, I try to get links from [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/). To do that, I write above code, and everything was good until come  that the line  "results=soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"photo-list-photo-interaction"})". Before that line I can take HTML code. However, in that line I couldn't got it.
How can I solve that problem. Thank you!

Comment: you can use flickr api instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of scraping with Beautiful Soup, why not use the [API](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/) instead? Alternatively, you could use [Flickr's RSS Feeds](https://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/) and parse them with the feedparser module.

If you still want to use BeautifulSoup:

```py
def flickr_photos(url):
    img_urls = []
    resp = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text)

    photos = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'view'})

    for photo in photos:
        try:
            img = photo['style'].split('(//').pop()
            if img.startswith('live'):
                img_urls.append(f'https://{img[:-1]}')
        except:
            pass
    return img_urls
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because Flickr has the image's url in the `background-image` style attribute.

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually, I use different websites to develop a toolkit. Not only Flickr.